# How to use locally hosted URLs of firebase function in frontend?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, paypal-sandbox, expo

Im using firebase functions for paypal, to test it locally I used the command firebase serve --only functions.Using this got the locally hosted URL's.When i try to add the URL in frontend(am using expo)it returns status as 500

Comment: It's hard to say why this is happening with seeing the minimal code that reproduces the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also note that `500` is just a generic "internal server error", which unfortunately is not very helpful for troubleshooting. Check for a more detailed message and at that to your question too.

Comment: I want to know it is possible to use firebase functions hosted URL's of free plan in frontend?